# How do I align the version numbers of my Epic and Steam versions so I can play together?

Tags: windows, networking, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

How do I align the version numbers of my Epic and Steam versions so I can play together?

The Epic Games version is BORDERLANDSTPS-2.0.0

The Steam version is BORDERLANDSTPS-1.0.7...

I've seen a downgrade online, that seems to be for 1.0.7... Could I apply that to my Epic Games version??

---

Or, do I get SHiFT accounts and use that to connect the games? Although, my Steam version doesn't seem to have any way to connect with SHiFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On or before September 9th, 2021, there was an update for the Steam versions of Borderlands 2 and TPS. It appears this is what it fixed.

---

Previous answer:

Ehh, you can just run multiple versions of the Steam version on your computer.  Just repeatedly open run the EXE, for Windows, or app, for Linux.

It's a **bit** of an FPS hit doing all four, and it's confusing too. You might not even have to go offline after the first instance for them to all LAN up.

Better to use multiple computers.

Oh, and only the online Steam version has the DLCs, so can't grind there.